# Generate Actual Business Time Spent resolving a ticket

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

How can I write a SQL query to calculate the actual time agents spend resolving a ticket, given that the company's business hours are between 8:30 AM and 5:30 PM Monday through Saturday, excluding minutes that are outside business hours? The reply time shown below disregards business hours i.e. the timer/counter includes minutes outside business hours. I want to deduct outside business hours minutes from the reply time

```
TICKET_ID   CREATED_AT  REPLY_TIME
157 2023-05-14 19:15:04.000 690
193 2023-05-20 11:11:19.000 2,634
72  2023-04-18 07:12:08.000 81
186 2023-05-19 07:04:23.000 16
165 2023-05-15 14:15:27.000 1
60  2023-04-04 08:10:52.000 1,344
32  2023-02-22 19:05:46.000 
93  2023-04-29 15:45:57.000 3,730
70  2023-04-15 16:47:07.000 2,268
83  2023-04-27 07:29:40.000
```

My snowflake sql looks something like this

```
WITH business_hours_calc AS (
    SELECT
        created_at,
        reply_time,
        DATEADD(
            SECOND,
            510 * 60, -- 510 minutes (8 hours and 30 minutes) in seconds
            TIMESTAMP_FROM_PARTS(
                YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created_at ))),
                MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created_at ))),
                DAYOFMONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created_at ))),
                8, 30, 0, 0 -- 8:30 AM
            )
        ) AS start_time,
        DATEADD(
            SECOND,
            1020 * 60, -- 1020 minutes (17 hours) in seconds
            TIMESTAMP_FROM_PARTS(
                YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created_at ))),
                MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created_at ))),
                DAYOFMONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created_at))),
                17, 0, 0, 0 -- 5:00 PM
            )
        ) AS end_time,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, reply_time, created_at)
    FROM tickets_metrics
), 
time_diff_calc AS (
    SELECT
        created_at,
        reply_time,
        start_time,
        end_time,
        CASE
            WHEN TIME_SLICE(created_at, 1, 'HOUR')::TIME BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
            THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN TIME_SLICE(DATEADD(MINUTE, reply_time, created_at), 1, 'HOUR')::TIME NOT BETWEEN start_time AND end_time 
                    THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(MINUTE, reply_time, created_at), end_time)
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ELSE 0
        END AS outside_business_hours_minutes
    FROM business_hours_calc
)
SELECT
    created_at,
    reply_time - outside_business_hours_minutes AS adjusted_reply_time
FROM time_diff_calc
LIMIT 10;
```

I get an incompatible types: [TIME(9)] and [TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)] error at the case statement level

Comment: Please don’t use images, only use editable text in your question. Please update your question with sample data, the result you want to achieve and the SQL you’ve managed to write on your own. Then ask a focussed question on a specific issue you are facing

Comment: I don't really understand what your data means. Is the reply time the time taken not considering business hours? If not, what's the end time for each row? In your SQL you've hardcoded 8 hours 30 mins and 17 hours - why? Which part of which CASE statement is giving you the error?

Comment: @NickW I have hardcoded 8hours 30 minutes in order to get the actual start time for business hours and the 17 hours so I can retrieve the business close time. I then use the two boundaries to check if tickets creation time + reply time falls within these boundaries or not. The issue in the case statement arises here 
```
DATEADD(MINUTE, reply_time, created_at)
```

Comment: The error you are seeing is due to the fact that you are casting the result of the TIME_SLICE calculations as TIME for some reason. If you remove these then your code runs. However outside_business_hours_minutes is always evaluating as zero so I'm guessing your logic is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this
https://docs.getdbt.com/blog/measuring-business-hours-sql-time-on-task
Tweaked it to suit my needs

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to find the intersection of timestamp ranges between when a ticket was opened/resolved and business hours.

```
WITH BUSINESS_HOURS AS (
{# 
  First establish ranges for your business hours (8:30-5:30 Mon-Sat) relevant to the time period of the tickets. 
  You don't mention what time zone this is, so I'm assuming everything is UTC.
#}
    SELECT
        TO_TIMESTAMP(DS.DATE_DAY || ' 08:30:00') STARTS_AT,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(DS.DATE_DAY || ' 17:30:00') ENDS_AT
    FROM ({{ dbt_utils.date_spine(datepart="day", 
                                start_date="(SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', MIN(CREATED_AT))::DATE FROM MY_SOURCE_TABLE)",
                                end_date="(SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', MAX(DATEADD('minute', REPLY_TIME, CREATED_AT)))::DATE FROM MY_SOURCE_TABLE)") }}) DS
    WHERE DATE_PART('dayofweek', DS.DATE_DAY) != 6 {# 6 = Sunday #}
),
TICKET_HOURS AS (
{#
  Establish the timestamp range of the tickets.
#}
    SELECT
        TICKET_ID,
        CREATED_AT,
        DATEADD('minute', REPLY_TIME, CREATED_AT) RESOLVED_AT
    FROM MY_SOURCE_TABLE
),
TICKETS_ON_BUSINESS_HOURS AS (
{#
  Join using the formula startA <= endB AND endA >= startB to find the intersections. Each record will be at the grain of ticket + one business day.
#}
    SELECT
        TH.TICKET_ID,
        TH.CREATED_AT,
        TH.RESOLVED_AT,
        BH.STARTS_AT,
        BH.ENDS_AT,
        GREATEST(TH.CREATED_AT, BH.STARTS_AT) AS OVERLAP_STARTS_AT,
        LEAST(TH.RESOLVED_AT, BH.ENDS_AT) AS OVERLAP_ENDS_AT,
        DATEDIFF('minute', OVERLAP_STARTS_AT, OVERLAP_ENDS_AT) ACTUAL_TIME
    FROM TICKET_HOURS TH
    LEFT JOIN BUSINESS_HOURS BH ON TH.CREATED_AT <= BH.ENDS_AT AND TH.RESOLVED_AT >= BH.STARTS_AT
)

{# Finally, sum up the time for tickets that span multiple days #}
SELECT TICKET_ID, SUM(ACTUAL_TIME) TOTAL_TIME FROM TICKETS_ON_BUSINESS_HOURS GROUP BY 1
```